# Extract attribute value using css selectors

Tags: css, web-scraping, css-selectors

From the below HTML I am looking to extract the link in 'data-url' by using  CSS selectors only(No methods).

```
<a class="btn" data-url="https://example.com">
```

BTW, I am trying to scrape a website using a _*scraper* tool called **webscraper**.io, where the data to be extracted has to be specified using a CSS selector. Hence, I cannot make use of any useful methods from other programming languages.

Comment: css selectors match they don't extract.

Comment: @QHarr: Some web scraping tools include special, non-standard selectors (in the CSS selector syntax) that will actually do the extracting for you. webscraper.io seems to have a completely different definition of a "selector" *in addition to* the traditional "CSS selector" though and it looks like the asker is going to need both, given the way this tool is designed.

Comment: @QHarr: But this question is exceptional - in the vast majority of web scraping questions, that distinction doesn't actually matter. Any time someone asks to "extract [...] using selectors/XPath" it's pretty much implied that they want to 1) match elements using selectors, and *then* 2) extract data from whatever gets matched. The distinction becomes important once someone says they can only pass in a selector/XPath string, and even then they're probably already aware of the distinction.

Comment: @BoltClock I sit corrected :-) Definitely worth knowing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the url from the tag by using Element Attribute & then specifying the attribute name `data-url` in the attribute name field.

You can refer to the following sitemap for your reference.

```
{"_id":"stack-sample","startUrl":["http://elitesolution.co.in/sample/inde.html"],"selectors":[{"id":"a parent","type":"SelectorElementAttribute","parentSelectors":["_root"],"selector":"a","multiple":false,"extractAttribute":"data-url","delay":0}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is this:

```
.btn::after {
  content: ' ' attr(data-url);
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
  .btn::after {
content: ' ' attr(data-url);
  }
```

```html
<a class="btn" data-url="https://example.com">URL:</a>
```